# Specifying maximum number of cores for scikit-learn decomposition methods

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

I am running sklearn.decomposition.NMF on a compute cluster shared by many users at my institution. I am finding that NMF is frequently using all of the cores available on a node which can cause poor performance for that node for other users. As far as I know, there isn't an n_jobs/n_cores/n_threads parameter I can use to specify the maximum number of cores sklearn will use. Is there any approach that anyone is aware of to limit the number of cores used? It seems like the behavior is controlled by numpy so perhaps there is an environmental variable that needs to be set?

Answer (score 0):

I think adding:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=6;
```

before calling the job seems to be limiting the maximum number of threads used to 6